# How to dynamically assign value to Struts 2 textfield from Map

Tags: jsp, session, dictionary, struts2

I am trying to dynamically assign value to Struts2 textfield for that what i am doing id user Administrator is asked with a `userId` when he enters that Id that id is checked in DB if that id exists and it belongs to class employee I am passing object of class employee in using code

```
Map m = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
m.put("userDATA",o);
```

Where o is a object of class employee then my action class returns `SUCCESS` and O am redirected to page where I am displaying properties of Employee like `fName`, `lName` etc. but I am really struck with assigning dynamic value in struts textfield what I am doing is

```
<%Object o=session.getAttribute("userDATA");
Employee e=(Employee)o%>
```

and then I am doing

```
<s:textfield label="First Name" name="fName" value="%{e.fName}">
```

but I am getting nothing and yet I have already done `<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>`

Please help I am beginner in Struts2 and have basic knowledge of Struts only.

Comment: Spend some time with the documentation first; you're missing some very basic Struts 2 functionality. Also, using scriptlets is a poor practice and should be avoided, particularly when the framework provides documented mechanisms to get data from actions to the view layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
But now it's been resolved using this code.

```
<s:textfield label="First Name" name="fName" value="%{#session.userDATA}"/>
```

Thanks to Roman C.